# Database design for entities with many options

Tags: database-design, parse-platform

I am looking for the best approach to solve the following requirements. "Best" here means that performance beats "beautiful" design, I am not afraid of ugly, but performant designs.

Here are the constraints:

- I want to have several `Player` in my database. I expect to have 20k Players in there, at most.
- There is a bunch of `Game`s there, too - it's a list of about 500 Games. A game won't change once it's in there, but occasionally, a game will have to be added.
- The relationship between `Player` and `Game` is as follows: The player either plays a game or he doesn't, and he has a skill (Value from 1 to 5) for every game.

Now here's the part that really gives me headaches: I want to be able to search for multiple `Player` by specifying multiple `Game`s, a min skill and a max skill. So potentially, I have those 500 games, all compounded by OR, which makes a very long query which isn't very fast. My approach is that I should somehow get rid of the ORs and replace them by ANDs, but if someone is *not* looking for a specific `Game`, it means that he is looking for Players who play or don't play that particular Game (Because the user is interested in other Games).

I really hope I am missing something obvious or some trick that prevents me from having hundreds of OR-Clauses in every search request...

I tried it with Parse (hence the tag) and got an error: `{"code":154,"message":"too many $or clauses"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between `Player` and `Game` will be another table e.g. `Player_Game` with columns something like this:

- player_id (foreign key to Player)
- game_id (foreign key to Game)
- plays (yes or no)
- skill (integer 1-5)

So if you wanted to be able to search for multiple Players by specifying a **single** Game, a min skill and a max skill" the SQL query would be:

```
select player_id
from   player_game
where  game_id = {GAME_ID}
and    skill >= {MIN_SKILL}
and    skill <= {MAX_SKILL};
```

However, if the user can select multiple games it is harder.  Rather than construct a query with multiple `OR`s or a big `IN` list I would probably save the selected games to some kind of temporary table and then query:

```
select player_id
from   player_game
where  game_id in (select game_id from temp_games_list)
and    skill >= {MIN_SKILL}
and    skill <= {MAX_SKILL};
```

Comment: First: Yes, we are in the world of SQL, but I would be willing to switch to any other database. Currently, I use Parse, and they use - I think - MongoDB. Second: I updated the question for clarity. The pitfall is that the user is able to specify any game in his search, searching for players who play any of the selected games.

Comment: @PhilippFlenker In SQL, you could just use the `IN(...)` clause for that.

Comment: How exactly? Remember that a user can play multiple games. Unless I don't see the obvious, it's not trivial to use IN here.